# Get list of all System Databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I know how to fetch list of all databases present on particular Server.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM master.sys.databases
EXEC sp_databases
```

But, it gives me all database's like System as well as User Defined Databases.

I want to know how get a list of User Defined/System Databases only present in SQL Server as I am not able to see any column present in `master.sys.databases`, using which I can filter it to achieve my requirement.

Comment: System databases have an id of 4 or less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sys.databases` catalog view does not provide a column to distinguish between user and system databases. However, the names are well-known as listed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/system-databases) which may be used to exclude them as needed. Additionally, you may want to exclude the SSISDB catalog and distributor database, if present. Below is an example query.

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE
    name NOT IN(N'master',N'model',N'tempdb',N'msdb',N'SSISDB')
    AND is_distributor = 0;
```

BTW, this is a snippet of the query SSMS uses to enumerate system databases as gleaned from a trace:

```
WHERE
(CAST(case when dtb.name in (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'') then 1 else dtb.is_distributor end AS bit)=@_msparam_0)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for the Info. What is is_distributor means in this case ?

Comment: @AnujThite, a [distribution database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/distribution-database) is a database than can be created to support the SQL Server replication feature for various scenarios.